# Rest só retorna XML

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, rest, jax-rs

boa noite a todos,

estou fazendo um uma API RestFull pra mero aprendizado e esbarrei em um problema simples, mas não achei solução na internet.

criei essa classe pra fazer o controle de games:

```
@Path("/games")
public class ManipulaGameRest {

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List getListaGamesCadastrados(){
      return ControlaGame.getListaGames();
}
```

ao testar no postman ela funcionou perfeitamente, a primeira vista, porem ao tentar que o WS retornasse JSON, passando “Content-Type” como “application/json” ele ainda me retornou um XML…

tudo o que eu achei na net era pra colocar apenas o “MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON”, como não funcionou eu fiquei sem saber o q fazer.

alguem sabe me dizer como resolvo esse problema???

OBS: não ocorreu nenhum erro no console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma resposta no Stackoverflow internacional que você tem que anotar tua classe da seguinte forma:

```
@XmlRootElement
@GET @Produces("application/json")
```

> ```
> @XmlRootElement
>   public class MyJaxbBean {
>     public String name;
>     public int age;
>
>     public MyJaxbBean() {} // JAXB needs this
>
>     public MyJaxbBean(String name, int age) {
>       this.name = name;
>       this.age = age;
>     }
>   }
> and then your method would look like this:
>
>    @GET @Produces("application/json")
>    public MyJaxbBean getMyBean() {
>       return new MyJaxbBean("Agamemnon", 32);
>    }
> There is a chapter in the latest documentation that deals with this:
>
> https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json
> ```

Segue link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594945/how-correctly-produce-json-by-restful-web-service

Comment: ja tinha feito isso, não havia solucionado